# Upper bound on ratio of probability sums

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, inequality

Let us say I have some vector of probabilities $\vec{V}$ such that $\sum_i v_i = 1$.  I am trying to find a sharp upper bound on

$\frac{\sum_i v_i^3}{(\sum_i v_i^2)^2}$.  I can currently prove via Cauchy-Schwarz a very bad upper bound - this ratio must be less than the number of entries in the vector.  But I have numerical evidence that leads me to believe that something like 1.5 should be a sharp upper bound, not dependent on the vector length.

Comment: I deleted an answer that answered a wrong question. Just to be sure, you are looking at the smallest upper bound right?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to find a tight upper bound.

Comment: It is possible to exceed $1.5$ with for example one value of $\frac12$ and six values of $\frac{1}{12}$ to give $\frac{74}{49}\approx 1.51$.  I think the maximum grows like $O(\sqrt{n})$

Comment: I am certain this a problem in one of Vasile Cirtoaje's series of hard inequalities books. I will look at my dusty books over the weekend if no one answers it. Basically, one will have to invoke the EV theorem or something similar to conclude the maximum happens when something like $n-2$ or $n-1$ variables are equal.

Comment: @dezdichado Yes, Vasc's EV theorem works.

Comment: @dezdichado Amazing reference, I am going to look into the series.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Here is a upper bound**:

Assume that $n \ge 3$.
Denote
$S = \{(v_1, v_2, \cdots, v_n) : ~ v_i \ge 0, \forall i; ~ v_1 + v_2 + \cdots + v_n = 1\}.$

We have
$$\max_{(v_1, v_2, \cdots, v_n) \in S} \frac{\sum_i v_i^3}{(\sum_i v_i^2)^2} \le \frac{3\sqrt 3}{16}\sqrt n + \frac58 + \frac{5\sqrt 3}{96\sqrt n}. \tag{1}$$

The bound (1) satisfies that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{3\sqrt 3}{16}\sqrt n + \frac58 + \frac{5\sqrt 3}{96\sqrt n} - \max_{(v_1, v_2, \cdots, v_n) \in S} \frac{\sum_i v_i^3}{(\sum_i v_i^2)^2}\right) = 0. \tag{2}$$

---

**Proof of (1) and (2)**:

Consider the maximum of
$$f(v_1, v_2, \cdots, v_n) = \frac{\sum_i v_i^3}{(\sum_i v_i^2)^2}$$
subject to $v_i \ge 0, \forall i; ~ \sum_{i=1}^n v_i = 1$.

Using Vasc's Equal Variable Theorem (Corollary 1.9, [1]), $f$
is maximal when $0 \le v_1 = v_2 = \cdots = v_{n - 1} \le v_n$.

Letting $v_n = x$ and $v_1 = v_2 = \cdots = v_{n-1} = \frac{1 - x}{n-1}$, we have
$$\max_{(v_1, v_2, \cdots, v_n) \in S} \frac{\sum_i v_i^3}{(\sum_i v_i^2)^2} = \max_{x\in [0, 1]} \frac{(n^2 - 2n)x^3 + 3x^2 - 3x + 1}{(nx^2 - 2x + 1)^2}.$$

It suffices to prove that, for all $x\in [0, 1]$ and $n \ge 3$,
$$\frac{(n^2 - 2n)x^3 + 3x^2 - 3x + 1}{(nx^2 - 2x + 1)^2} \le \frac{3\sqrt 3}{16}\sqrt n + \frac58 + \frac{5\sqrt 3}{96\sqrt n}.$$

Letting $m = \sqrt{3n} - 3\ge 0$. After clearing the denominators, it suffices to prove that, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$a_1 x^4 + b_1x^3 + c_1x^2 + d_1 + e_1 \ge 0 \tag{3}$$
where
\begin{align*}
 a_1 &= 6\,{m}^{6}+128\,{m}^{5}+1115\,{m}^{4}+5100\,{m}^{3}+12960\,{m}^{2}+
 17388\,m+9639, \\
 b_1 &= -32\,{m}^{5}-552\,{m}^{4}-3792\,{m}^{3}-13020\,{m}^{2}-22392\,m-15444, \\
 c_1 &= 36\,{m}^{4}+552\,{m}^{3}+3270\,{m}^{2}+8460\,m+8118,\\
 d_1 &= -216\,{m}^{2}-1152\,m-1692, \\
 e_1 &= 54\,{m}^{2}+216\,m+207.
\end{align*}

We need the following auxiliary result.

**Fact 1**: Let $a_1 > 0, b_1, c_1, d_1, e_1$ be real numbers.
Let $f(x) = a_1x^4 + b_1x^3 + c_1x^2 + d_1x + e_1$.
Let $\Delta_f$ denote its discriminant.
Let
$D_f = 64a_1^3e_1-16a_1^2c_1^2+16a_1b_1^2c_1
-16a_1^2b_1d_1-3b_1^4$.
If $\Delta_f \ge 0$ and $D_f > 0$, then $f(x)\ge 0$ for any real number $x$.
(See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function and the reference [13] therein,
i.e., Rees, E. L. (1922). "Graphical Discussion of the Roots of a Quartic Equation". The American Mathematical Monthly. 29 (2): 51–55.)

We have
\begin{align*}
 \Delta_f &= 63700992\, \left( 6\,{m}^{2}+24\,m+23 \right)\\
 &\qquad \times  \left( 512\,{m}^{5}+
 5886\,{m}^{4}+26604\,{m}^{3}+57887\,{m}^{2}+58242\,m+19326 \right) \\
 &\qquad \times
 \left( {m}^{2}+6\,m+6 \right) ^{4} \left( m+3 \right) ^{6}\\
 &> 0 
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
 D_f &= 12288\, \left( 4\,{m}^{6}+96\,{m}^{5}+916\,{m}^{4}+4460\,{m}^{3}+11389
 \,{m}^{2}+13734\,m+5262 \right) \\
 &\qquad \times \left( 8\,{m}^{5}+138\,{m}^{4}+900\,{
  m}^{3}+2769\,{m}^{2}+4086\,m+2358 \right)  \left( m+3 \right) ^{9}\\
 &> 0.
\end{align*}

By Fact 1, (3) is true.

(2) is true since
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{3\sqrt 3}{16}\sqrt n + \frac58 + \frac{5\sqrt 3}{96\sqrt n} - f\Big(\sqrt{3/n}\Big)\right) = 0$$
where
$$f(x) := \frac{(n^2 - 2n)x^3 + 3x^2 - 3x + 1}{(nx^2 - 2x + 1)^2}.$$

We are done.

---

*Reference*:

[1] Vasile Cirtoaje, “The Equal Variable Method”, J. Inequal. Pure and Appl. Math., 8(1), 2007.
Online: https://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/059_06_JIPAM/059_06.pdf

Comment: Note that your $\frac{3\sqrt 3}{16}\approx 0.32476$ so between my $0.32$ and my $\frac13$

Comment: @Henry Yes, actually, it is the asymptotic expansion of $\max f(v)$ (if we use the closed form $x$ due to Michael Rozenberg), although I did not based on his result.

Comment: This is an amazing result, and much more complicated that I believed.  Thank you!

Comment: @librus You are welcome. My proof is complicated. Perhaps there are simpler proofs.

Answer (score 3):

Empirically it looks to me as if there is an upper bound which is $O(\sqrt{n})$ and in particular your expression can be above $0.32 \sqrt{n}$ but will never exceed  $\frac{\sqrt{n}+2}{3}$ for all vector lengths $n$.

So for example with a vector of length $n=100$, this suggests the maximum possible is somewhere between $3.2$ and $4$.  Consider the case where $x_1=0.1585$ and  the other ninety-nine $x_i$ are all equal to $0.0085$; your expression would then be about $3.88$.

I suspect it would be possible to prove that the maximal case has

- one value is $x$ and the other $n-1$ values are $\frac{1-x}{n-1}$
- where $x$ is the largest root of $(n^2-2n)x^3+3nx^2-3nx+1=0$

---

*Added later*

Based on River Li and Michael Rozenberg's anaysis, we can tighten this: the maximum possible value is between $$\frac{3\sqrt 3}{16}\sqrt{n} +\frac58 \qquad\text{ and } \qquad\frac{3\sqrt 3}{16}\sqrt{n} +1-\frac{3\sqrt 3}{16}$$  so numerically between $$0.32475\sqrt{n} +0.625\qquad\text{ and } \qquad 0.32476\sqrt{n} +0.67524.$$ My empirical results were consistent with this.

Comment: someone claims $\frac{9}{8}\sqrt{n}$ as a bound but no one provided a proof here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1329668p7162129

Comment: @dezdichado That is a larger than my assertion, so I would expect it to be true but looser than necessary. Note that its sum seems to be over $n+1$ terms rather than $n$  so the $\frac98$ is introduced to cover the case when  you have two terms of $\frac12\pm \frac1{2\sqrt{3}}$ with the expression being $\frac98$. If its sum had been over $n$ terms, it could have used $\sqrt{n}$ but still looser than mine when $n>1$.

Comment: @Henry I proved that your suspecting is right! See please my post.

Answer (score 3):

The Henry's suspecting is right!

Indeed, let also $\sum\limits_{i=1}^nv_1^2=constant$ and $n>1$.

Thus, by the Vasc's E-V Method(see here https://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/059_06_JIPAM/059_06.pdf Corollary 1.5)

it's enough to find a maximal value for $v_1=v_2=...=v_{n-1}\leq v_n$.

From here, as Henry says, we have,  $v_n=x$, where $x\in[0,1]$,  $$v_1=...=v_{n-1}=\frac{1-x}{n-1}$$ and $$\frac{1-x}{n-1}\leq x,$$ which gives $$\frac{1}{n}\leq x\leq1.$$
Thus, we need to find $$\max_{\frac{1}{n}\leq x\leq1}\frac{\frac{(1-x)^3}{(n-1)^2}+x^3}{\left(\frac{(1-x)^2}{n-1}+x^2\right)^2}.$$
Now, $$\left(\frac{\frac{(1-x)^3}{(n-1)^2}+x^3}{\left(\frac{(1-x)^2}{n-1}+x^2\right)^2}\right)'=\frac{(1-nx)((n^2-2n)x^3+3nx^2-3nx+1)}{(nx^2-2x+1)^3}.$$
We can show that for $n>2$ $$x_{max}=\frac{2\sqrt{n-1}\cos\frac{\pi-\arccos\frac{2\sqrt{n-1}}{n}}{3}-1}{n-2}.$$
For $n=2$ $x_{\max}=\frac{1+\sqrt3}{2\sqrt3}.$

I hope it will help.

Comment: The closed form $x$ is nice.

Comment: and for $n=1$ you obviously have $x=1$

Comment: Yes, of course!